# how to check if an object is object[0]?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dynamicobject

In debug mode, I'm hovering over my variable, and it shows that it is **{object[0]}**:

[image]

However, this IF statement is never getting triggered.

**How do I check for this object[0] type?**

Comment: `object[0]` could mean its an empty collection its hard to say. where does this object come from?

Comment: What does element.GetType().FullName return in this case?

Comment: You if statement doesn't seem to make much sense. Could you please update the answer an explain why you're using this check?

Comment: Or provide some more code for context.

Comment: An array is an `IEnumerable`, so maybe you could change to `element is IEnumerable && ...`

Comment: Your screenshot shows that while you're inspecting `element`'s value, you're not inspecting it when the execution is on the `if` condition. You also don't show what `ToEnumerable()` does, so there's no telling what that returns. It wouldn't surprise me if it's a collection containing `element`.

Comment: And if you happen to be using [Telerik's `CollectionExtensions`](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/api/html/m_telerik_windows_controls_collectionextensions_toenumerable__1.htm), that's *exactly* what its `ToEnumerable` does. It always returns an enumerable containing exactly one item, so `!element.ToEnumerable().Any()` will always be false, regardless of the value of `element`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check that an `object` is a `object[]`, your check `element is object[]` is already correct.

To check that an `object[]` is empty, calling `Any()` is already correct, but make sure to call it on the right instance. Avoid that `ToEnumerable()` extension method, since it's not doing what you're hoping for.

```
if (element is object[] && !((object[]) element).Any())
    // element is an empty array of objects
```

Test:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Tester {
    static class Program {
        static void Test(string name, object element) {
            Console.Write($"{name}: ");
            Console.WriteLine(element is object[] && !((object[])element).Any());
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Test("new object()",       new object());       // false
            Test("new { }",            new { });            // false
            Test("new object[0]",      new object[0]);      // true
            Test("new object[1]",      new object[1]);      // false

            Test("new List<object>()", new List<object>()); // false
            // Note: object[] o = new List<object>(); wouldn't be allowed.

            Test("new string[0]",      new string[0]);      // true
            // Note: object[] o = new string[0]; would be allowed.

            Test("new int[0]",         new int[0]);         // false
            // Note: object[] o = new int[0]; wouldn't be allowed.
        }
    }
}
```

This includes some test cases that could be an indication that the check you're attempting to do isn't a good idea, but it also indicates that it gives accurate results.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `object[0]` type. What it's telling you is that it's an empty array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
var test = element as IEnumerable;

If (test != null && test.Any())
{
```

Comment: i have, and it looks like if element is a Guid then it is an IEnumerable

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' No, [`Guid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't implement `IEnumerable`. Maybe you're looking at a [`string`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) which happens to represent a Guid? `string` implements `IEnumerable`.